What is the use of layout.tsx in react native expo?
Previously I was Using js for writing react native expo code but now the typescript has become default language for expo(it was already the default language for react native CLI), so I'm a bit confused the new changes.
We have to write our code in a file named index.tsx which is inside the app directory and layout.tsx is also inside the same directory and it has stack navigation code written as default but I can't add another screens correctly.
My main problem is navigation between screen
I did everything that I could.

Following the React native docs , It mentions -

_layout.web.js file is used as a layout on the web and _layout.js is used on all other platforms.
index.js file is used as the home page for all platforms.

From the docs - "Layout files in a directory are used to define shared UI elements such as headers, tab bars so that they persist between different routes."
So say you have a header that should be there in both the urls \home and \about. Then you add that header in _layout.tsx file which then loads the header in both the urls. This happens because the routing is file-based. For instance in your app folder, you may place three files - _layout.tsx, home.tsx and about.tsx. Then the \home url renders app\home.tsx file and similarly for about page. In both the files, _layout renders the header.
Go throught the following links for better understanding in docs -

File based routing and _layout file desc
Routing

